# React displaying fetched data issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a React project and having an issue when trying to display data that I just fetched.

```js
...

const [clientImport, setClientImport] = useState(null);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
const fetchData = async() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/client');
  setClientImport(result);
  console.log(result);
  console.log(clientImport);
};
const formChange = (e) => {
  setIsLoading(false);
  console.log(clientImport.data[2].nom);
  const value = e.target.value;
  setState({
    ...state,
    [e.target.name]: value
  })
}
return <div>
          <Calendar getDate={getDate}/>
             <Form> {isLoading ? (<div>Loading ...</div>) : (<div>aze and {clientImport.data[2].nom}</div>)}

...
```

So my fetch is working, I tested it out in the `formChange` method, and I get a result for `clientImpot.data[2].nom`.

But whenever I try to display the same thing in the JSX, I get a

> TypeError: clientImport is null.

The version above gives me the error. When I delete `{clientImport.data[2].nom}` it works fine.

Whenever I try to display any `clientImport` values into the return, it doesn't work.

This is just for debugging that i put in there, the goal is to put it in there ultimately to map:

```js
<Form.Group as={Col} lg={5} controlId="formClient">
  <Form.Label>Client - </Form.Label>
  <Form.Control as="select" onChange={updateClientChoice}>
    <option key={-2} ></option>
    <option key={-1} value="newClient">Ajouter un nouveau client</option>
    {clientImport.data.map((c, i) => (
    <option key={i} value={c.id}>{c.name} - {c.prenom} - {}</option>))}
  </Form.Control>
</Form.Group>
```

Thanks for your help ;).

Edit:
For a bit more infos:

when i do this : `const [clientImport, setClientImport] = useState(null);`

with this : `clientImport.data.map`

It returns : `TypeError: clientImport is null`

But if i declare it with ''(or[]) like :
`const [clientImport, setClientImport] = useState('');`

it shows : `TypeError: imports.client.data is undefined`

Idk if that can help but i'm kinda stucked here :p.

Answer (score 0):

That's why the following functions are not ran in turn.

setClientImport(data)
setIsLoading(false)

You try to show clinetImport data when isLoading is false.
Once above functions are ran, isLoading becomes false first, and then clientImport is updated.
When isLoading is updated, react tries to render again, but at that time, clientImport is null.

You need to update like

```
<Form>      {isLoading || clientImport === null? (
                                        <div>Loading ...</div>
                                      ) : (<div>aze and {clientImport.data[2].nom}</div>)}
```

Comment: Yea i actually messed that up while trying to debug, my bad, the code is not clear, but the error persist.
Whenever i try to render clientImport it shows me that error.
I can delete all the loading thing and it will still do that.
If i put {clientImport.data[2].nom} wherever in the return function, the same error is shown, independently of the loading.
And the data is there, since it shows well in the formChange(which is called everytime i input anything in the form).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I needed to declare my import as :

```
const [clientImport, setClientImport] = useState([]);
```

the fetch like :

```
const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/client');
        setclientImport(result.data);
```

and for the map :

```
clientImport.map
```

The issue apparently as that i declared as null and changed the type, and it's a bad idea to change types :p.